# No icon for chat messages in the feed

Tags: bug, ios-app, ios-app-feed

When I open the feed view on the iOS app, I can't see any icon for chat replies:

> [image: Chat reply]

It would be great to draw something here.

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)